# Microsoft Edge browser coding

Tags: microsoft-edge

If I develop a website, will it run on IE11, Chrome, Firefox and edge in the same manner or do we need to code specially for IE11? I don't have windows 8 and hence couldn't test my applications on edge browser.

Answer (score 4):

We have a number of tutorials and labs on [how to do interoperable website development here.](http://www.davevoyles.com/interoperable-web-development/)

You can do cross browser testing [without having Edge on your machine](https://github.com/deltakosh/interoperable-web-development/tree/master/testing), too.

**Testing the application using RemoteIE & BrowserStack**

In this lab you will learn about different ways to test websites that don't involve a lab with physical machines or devices that you manually interact with.

There are several ways of testing websites, aside from the good old-fashioned way of using a device lab and physically looking at your site on multiple devices and in multiple browsers. Two of the more popular and easier ways to go about testing include modern.IE remoteIE and BrowserStack.

**RemoteIE**

RemoteIE is a free service offered by modern.IE that allows you to connect to a hosted version of the latest IE builds running in the cloud using a client. This client, called the Azure RemoteApp Client, is available for Mac OS X, iOS, Android and Windows OS devices, and includes simple installation and account set up steps. The available IE builds run on Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise. In this preview version of the service, only public URLs and IP addresses can be accessed.

Other tools offered by modern.IE include:

- Virtual Machines with versions of IE ranging from IE6 to IE11, that
  can be downloaded and managed in your own development environment.
- Browser Screenshots of how your site looks across nine common
  browsers and devices.
- Compatibility reports generated from analyzing your site while it
  runs to detect patterns of interactions known to cause issues in
  browsers.
- Site scans for common coding problems in your website.

**BrowserStack**

RemoteIE has partnered with BrowserStack to provide interactive browser testing in the cloud, regardless of the platform, and within your own browser.

BrowserStack is a paid online service, but you can sign up for a free trial. With BrowserStack it is possible to test internal websites or local html designs using remote browsers after configuring for local testing, so the website does not have to be live to test it out. Signing up for the free trial gives you a 30-minute session to test the website in a broad range of platforms and browsers. The full list of browsers & mobile devices for live testing can be found here.

**Testing the website using BrowserStack**

You will now test your website in different browsers using BrowserStack. In order to do this, you need to have the website running, sign up for a free trial of BrowserStack and configure it for local debugging. The following steps will take you through this process, and then you can start testing the website.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft Edge browser is using the following user agent string:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0
```

If you develop a website using web standards, it will run on IE11, Chrome, Firefox and edge in the same manner. Edge is running on Windows 10 and you will not be able to test it on a Windows 8 device. but on a Windows 10 device you can test for IE11.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Edge will only be available on Windows 10, not 8.

Here's how Edge stacks up against other browsers in terms of HTML5 support.
http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-43/firefox-38/ie-Edge/ie-11.html

Comment: what about css,javascript,jQuery support of Edge.? where can we check that ?

Comment: @RBP css: http://caniuse.com/#cats=CSS javascript https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/